# 画面をロードしたときに最小化もしくは非表示にする方法はありますか？

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

■質問事項
ざっくりとした質問で大変恐縮ですが、
HTTPリクエストで遷移したHTMLファイルについて、
ロード時に画面を最小化もしくは非表示にして表示することは可能でしょうか？

■これまでに試した方法
　・最小化
　　HTML内に埋め込んだjavascriptで

```css
　　　
 　 　  window.minimize();
```

と記述しましたが動作しませんでした。
　
・非表示
　　私が調べた限りでは有効な手立てが見つかりませんでした。。

■背景
遷移後処理を実行するために一瞬だけ表示される画面のため
最小化か非表示にしたほうが見栄えが良いなと思い、このような実装を考えています。

宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: どういった処理フローを想定しているのでしょうか，質問文から読み取れる情報であれば「即座にリダイレクトする」「そもそも画面遷移は行わずに所謂ajaxでバックグラウンドでリクエストを行う」といった手段が一般に取られるシチュエーションに見えますが．

Answer (score 2):

読み込み先のページをCSSで非表示状態にしておき、処理完了後表示するのが簡単ではないかと思います

```html
<body id="body" style="visibility: hidden;">
 <main>aaa</main>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
// 3秒後に表示
setTimeout(function () {
  console.log("done");
  const body = document.querySelector("#body");
  body.style.visibility = "visible"
}, 3000);
</script>
```

`window.minimize` は調べた限りモダンブラウザだと実装されてなさそうですね